# How to re-order an Eloquent collection?

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I've got a collection of records retrieved via a relationship, and I'd like to order them by the `created_at` field. Is this possible in Eloquent?

Here is how I am retrieving the collection:

`$skills = $employee->skills;`

I'd like to order this `$skills` collection by their creation. I've tried `$skills->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');` but the Collection class does not have an `orderBy` method.

I guess this problem is very simple and I'm missing something..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is failing is that `orderBy` is a query method not a collection method.

If you used `$skills = $employee->skills()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();`, this would query the skills in the order you want.

Alternatively, if you already had a collection that you wanted to re-order, you could use the `sortBy` or `sortByDesc` methods.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in two ways. Either you can `orderBy` your results while query, as in

```
$employee->skills()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

**OR**

You can use `sortBy` and `sortByDesc` on your `collection`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `orderBy` constraint on the query instead of the relationship.

For e.g,

```
$employees = Employee::where('salary', '>', '50000') // just an example
                      ->with('skills')  // eager loading the relationship
                      ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                      ->get();
```

and then:

```
foreach($employees as $employee) 
{
    var_dump($employee->skill);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results to **always** be ordered by a field, you can specify that on the relationship:

**Employee.php**

```
public function skills() {
    return $this->hasMany(Skills::class)->orderBy('created_at');
}
```

If you just want to order them sometimes, you can use `orderBy()`, but on the relationship, not the property:

```
$skills = $employee->skills()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection has `sortBy` and `sortByDesc`

```
$skills = $skills->sortBy('created_at');
$skills = $skills->sortByDesc('created_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

This Stackoverflow question askes how to order an Eloquent collection. However, I would like to propose a different solution to use instead given the example in the question. I would like to recommend to [use an ordering on the query itself for performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60188232/12355272).

Like @Don't Panic proposes you can specify a default ordering on the relationship for great reusability convenience:

`app/Models/Employee.php`

```
public function skills() {
    return $this->hasMany(Skills::class)->orderBy('created_at');
}
```

However, if you have already set an ordering on your query like we do in the code above, any additional orderings will be ignored. So that is a bummer if you want to use a different sorting in another situation. To overwrite this default ordering and re-order the query with a new ordering, one needs to use the [`reorder()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#removing-existing-orderings). For example:

```
// Get a Collections of Skill-models ordered by the oldest skill first.
$skills = $employee->skills()->reorder()->orderByDesc('created_at')->get();

// Same result as the previous example, but different syntax.
$skills = $employee->skills()->reorder()->oldest()->get();

// Or just give some arguments to the reorder() method directly:
$skills = $employee->skills()->reorder('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```