# Is Laravel sortBy slower or heavier to run than orderBy?

Tags: laravel

My concern is that while orderBy is applied to the query, I'm not sure how the sortBy is applied?

The reason for using sortBy in my case is because I get the collection via the model (i.e. `$user->houses->sortBy('created_at')`).

I'm just concerned about the performance: is sortBy simply looping each object and sorting them?, or is Laravel smart enough to simply transform the sortBy into an orderBy executed within the original query?

Answer (score 1):

You need `orderBy` in order to perform a SQL order.

```php
$user->houses()->orderBy('created_at')->get()
```

You can also eager load the houses in the right order to avoid N+1 queries.

```php
$users = User::with(['houses' => function ($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('created_at');
}])->get();

$orderedHouses = $users->first()->houses;
```

The `sortBy` method is applied to the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections) so indeed, it will looping each objects.

Answer (score 1):

The `orderBy()` method is much more efficient than the `sortBy()` method when querying databases of a non-trivial size / at least 1000+ rows. This is because the `orderBy()` method is essentially planning out an SQL query that has not yet run whereas the `sortBy()` method will sort the result of a query.

For reference, it is important to understand the difference between a Collection object and a Builder object in Laravel.

A builder object is, essentially, an SQL query that has not been run. In contrast, a collection is essentially an array with some extra functionality/methods added. Sorting an array is much less efficient than pulling the data from the DB in the correct format on the actual query.

example code :

```
<?php
// Plan out a query to retrieve the posts alphabetized Z-A
// This is still a query and has not actually run
$posts = Posts::select('id', 'created_at', 'title')->orderBy('title', 'desc');

// Now the query has actually run. $posts is now a collection.
$posts = $posts->get();

// If you want to then sort this collection object to be ordered by the created_at 
timestamp, you *could* do this.
// This will run quickly with a small number or rows in the result,
// but will be essentially unusable/so slow that your server will throw 500 errors
// if the collection contains hundreds or thousands or objects.
$posts = $posts->sortBy('created_at');
```